# sqldatasource and a Grid delete command error

Tags: asp.net

I am using sqldatasource to binding to the grid. 
SqlDatasource is  like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_ValidUsers" runat="server" 

                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>" 

                                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString.ProviderName %>" 
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT ValidUsers.ID, ValidUsers.DomainID, ValidUsers.isAdmin, ValidUsers.isSubmitToTimberline, ValidUsers.isHistoryDetails, ValidUsers.isSearch, ValidUsers.isAttachments, ValidUsers.isUpload, ValidUsers.isDelete, a.Name AS FullName, a.DepartmentCode FROM ValidUsers INNER JOIN db_common.dbo.DomainUsers_Active AS a ON a.DomainID = ValidUsers.DomainID WHERE (ISNULL(a.DomainID, '') NOT IN ('', 'XX0000'))" 
                                                UpdateCommand="UPDATE ValidUsers SET isAdmin = ?, isSubmitToTimberline = ?, isHistoryDetails = ?,isSearch = ?, isAttachments = ?, isUpload = ?, isDelete = ? WHERE (ID = ?)"                                              
                                                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM ValidUsers WHERE (ID = ?)">
                                                <DeleteParameters>
                                                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                                                </DeleteParameters>
                                              <UpdateParameters>
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isAdmin" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isSubmitToTimberline" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isHistoryDetails" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isSearch" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isAttachments" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isUpload" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isDelete" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
                                                </UpdateParameters>

                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>When I click delete,  I am getting following error. I don’t have a clue where this
```

> parameter 1 and 2 are coming from?
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Command parameter[1] '' is invalid.
>   Command parameter[2] '' is invalid.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code for the SqlDataSource?

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString %>" 

                                                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conString.ProviderName %>" 
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT ValidUsers.ID, ValidUsers.DomainID, ValidUsers.isAdmin, ValidUsers.isSubmitToTimberline, ValidUsers.isHistoryDetails, ValidUsers.isSearch, ValidUsers.isAttachments, ValidUsers.isUpload, ValidUsers.isDelete, a.Name AS FullName, a.DepartmentCode FROM ValidUsers INNER JOIN db_common.dbo.DomainUsers_Active AS a ON a.DomainID = ValidUsers.DomainID WHERE (ISNULL(a.DomainID, '') NOT IN ('', 'XX0000'))" 
                                                UpdateCommand="UPDATE ValidUsers SET isAdmin = ?, isSubmitToTimberline = ?, isHistoryDetails = ?,isSearch = ?, isAttachments = ?, isUpload = ?, isDelete = ? WHERE (ID = ?)"                                                 
                                                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM ValidUsers WHERE (ID = ?)">
                                                <DeleteParameters>
                                                    <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                                                </DeleteParameters>
                                                <UpdateParameters>
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isAdmin" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isSubmitToTimberline" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isHistoryDetails" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isSearch" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isAttachments" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isUpload" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="false" Name="isDelete" Type="Boolean" />
                                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
                                                </UpdateParameters>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: @user643062 - You should update this in your question itself rather than adding an Answer. Please edit your question and update this code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

So is update working properly? ID is the primary Key right?

Try setting **DataKeyName="ID"** for your GV and **remove the DeleteParameters** from SqlDataSource.

**Edit:**
I would suggest you to follow [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs) to setup your sqldatasource for Update and Delete. It could be some parameters issue. I would also suggest to handle [SqlDataSource Update event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updated.aspx#Y124) and check for e.Exception to info.

Comment: NO update is also not working. I tried adding DataKeyName="id" now javascript error is not coming but update and delete nothing works.